# Joomla 3, How can I access the server side code?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I need to know how I would be able to access and modify existing or add my own custom server side code to my Joomla! 3 website. I have tried numerous keyword searches and also tried searching through the forums, etc, and can not find anything. I can add inline JavaScript to my web pages with Sourcerer extension but need to be able to add server side code, say to process a form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Sourcerer may make things quick, but spend some time looking into plugins, modules, templates and components. That's the right way of extending the Joomla framework.  There are plenty of tutorials on creating these on Joomla's website.

For a single form, a module is probably what you'd need.

Sourcerer adds lots of display code to your database, which really isn't very good from the perspective of keeping things tidy.  Trying to tidy up or re-skin a site built using sourcerer is a nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the PHP, HTML, and CSS files in your Joomla installation folder on your server they are in your template settings.

Answer (score 0):

Processing server-side code is main purpose and reason for existence of Joomla extensions, mainly components. There are thousands of extensions available on [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/), and many of them are dealing with [Forms](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms), out of which most popular are [RSForms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/rsform-pro) and [Breezing Forms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/breezingforms).